# I am getting error as io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error while connecting to server

Tags: android, socket.io

I'm working on an application which connects to socket.io server and fetches realtime data.
But while connecting to socket.io I am getting following error `io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error` 
I also tried to set transport in socket.io client and also tried ping from my emulator to server and it's working fine but still, I am getting the above error.

This is what I have tried.

**Client side code**

```
 socket1 = IO.socket("http://127.0.0.1:3000");            //Sending data to topic
 socket1.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
     @Override
     public void call(Object... args) {
         Log.d(TAG, "call: Socket Connected.. "+args);
     }
 }).on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, new Emitter.Listener() {
     @Override
     public void call(Object... args) {
         if (args != null) {
             for (Object o : args) {
                 Log.e(TAG, o.toString());
             }
         }
     }
 }).on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, new Emitter.Listener() {
     @Override
     public void call(Object... args) {
         Log.e(TAG, "Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT");
     }
 }).on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
     @Override
     public void call(Object... args) {
         Log.e(TAG, "Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT");
     }
 }).on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECTING, new Emitter.Listener() {
     @Override
     public void call(Object... args) {
         Log.d(TAG, "Socket is connecting");
     }
 });
 socket1.connect();
```

**Server side code**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('<h2>Hello world</h2>');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: Still not found any solution can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(socket.id + '  servidor conectado');
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log(socket.id + ' server offline');
});
```

});

Comment: thanks for your response @Felipe I solved this error.

Comment: Welcome bro. I was the same problem :/